# How can I disable this mutli-monitor window-cutoff in Mavericks?

Tags: display, macos

If I drag a window in between two screens, half the window disappears. Is there a flag I can set from the command line or pref option somewhere to disable this?

My chrome window below is in the middle of my two monitors with the left half hidden.
[image]

Comment: have you tried system pref > mission control > and uncheck "displays have separate spaces" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried system pref > mission control > and uncheck "displays have separate spaces"[image: U]

Comment: This answer is still valid for Big Sur!

Answer (score 2):

Try going to **System Preferences** → **Mission Control** → and unchecking the option for **Displays have separate Spaces**.

Comment: Feel free to delete this answer, once @Macmaniman has returned  and answered himself